# How do I write comments with telethon (python)?

Tags: python, telethon

I would like to write a comment under the post in a  telegram channel with telethon. How do i dot that?

I have tried this, but it didnt work:

```
posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
        peer=name,
        limit=1,
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=0,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
        add_offset=0,
        hash=0))
posts.messages[0].reply("...")
```

Comment: what libraries did you use?

Comment: Abdel, telethon.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
        peer=name,
        limit=1,
        offset_date=None,
        offset_id=0,
        max_id=0,
        min_id=0,
        add_offset=0,
        hash=0))

post = posts.messages[0]
client.send_message(entity = name, message="w", comment_to=post)
```